# How to return an array for unit testing with JUnit and Mockito?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am testing an application that will stop unless it can split a `String` into a `String[]`. I am using JUnit and Mockito to test the application. I set up a default value and the mock behavior as follows.

`String[] exampleStringList = {"exampleElement", "exampleElement"};
when(example.Call()).thenReturn(exampleStringList);`

This creates the error `java: no suitable method found for thenReturn(java.Util.String[])`. I tried to resolve the issue by substituting `String[]` with `List<String>` and then adding the necessary elements. This created the same error as above.

TL;DR; I need to return a `String[]` with elements using JUnit for testing purposes but thenReturn is not compatible. How can I use JUnit and Mockito to return a `String[]` array to the test?

Comment: Please add the code of the class in question (one you're trying to mock).

Comment: The most I can show is `String exampleStringArr[] = mockedMethod.getData().split("/");`

Comment: What's the return type of `example.Call();`? The `.thenReturn(exampleStringList);` should provide the same return type as the method.

Comment: @Jizzle21013 I meant the signature of the `Call()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to recreate you scenario,

1. Service definition

   ```
   public interface ExampleService {
   boolean doSomething();
   ```

   }
2. Implementation

   ```
   @Service
   @RequiredArgsConstructor
   public class ExampleServiceImpl implements ExampleService {
   private final ExampleDependantService exampleDependantService;
    @Override
   public boolean doSomething() {
   String[] strings = exampleDependantService.call();
   if(strings.length >0){
       return true;
   }else{
       return false ;
   }

    }
   }
   ```
3. Dependency

   ```
     @Component
     public class ExampleDependantService {
     public String[] call(){
      return new String[]{"exampleElement", "exampleElement"};
     }
     }
   ```

4.Test

```
       @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
       class ExampleDependantServiceImplTest {
       @Mock
       private ExampleDependantService exampleDependantService;
       @InjectMocks
       private ExampleServiceImpl exampleServiceImpl;

      @Test
      void doSomething_WhenCalled() {
      String[] exampleStringList = {"exampleElement", "exampleElement"};
      when(exampleDependantService.call()).thenReturn(exampleStringList);
      boolean b = exampleServiceImpl.doSomething();
       Assert.assertTrue(b);
      }
      }
```

5.Output

[image]